# How to efficiently load data from CSV into Database?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, database-performance

I have a CSV/TSV file with data and want to load that CSV data into Database. I am using Java or Python and PostgreSQL to do that (I can't change that).

The problem is that for each row I make an INSERT query and it is not that efficient if I have let's say 600.000 rows. Is there any more efficient way to do it?

I was wondering if I can take more rows and create just one big query and execute it on my database but I'm not sure if that helps at all or should I divide the data in maybe let's say 100 pieces and execute 100 queries?

Comment: The answer is yes you can. I think you are searching for something what is named "batch insertion". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres

Comment: thank you, @ZiemowitStolarczyk :)

Answer (score 2):

If the CSV file is compatible with the format required by [`copy from stdin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), then the most efficient way is to use the `CopyManager` API.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18608479/330315) for example code.

---

If your input file isn't compatible with Postgres' copy command, you will need to write the INSERT yourself. But you can speed up the process by using JDBC batching:

Something along the lines:

```java
PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement("insert into ...");
int batchSize = 1000;
int batchRow = 0;
// iterate over the lines from the file
while (...) {
   ... parse the line, extract the columns ...
   insert.setInt(1, ...);
   insert.setString(2, ...);
   insert.setXXX(...);
   insert.addBatch();
   batchRow ++;
   if (batchRow == batchSize) {
     insert.executeBatch();
     batchRow = 0);
   }
}
insert.executeBatch();
```

Using `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` in your [JDBC URL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) will improve performance even more.

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server can access the file directly, you could try using the [COPY FROM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command. If your CSV is not of the right format it might still be faster to transcript it to something the COPY command will handle (e.g. while copying to a location that the server can access).

Comment: Never mind, seems  Ziemowit Stolarczyk already linked to an answer with pretty much the same idea, but better explained =)