# How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table via java code?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a `csv` file which I want to import to table in `postgres`

The table contains 3 fields (`id text, name text, geo geometry`).
The `csv` file is in the same format (3 values separate with comma).

I want to use java code in order to import the file (`input.csv`) into the table (`tbl`)

How can I do it ?
Is there a query which I pass the file path to the DB ?

Comment: "Is there a query which I pass the file path to the DB" - will the file be accessible from the database server (by the PostgreSQL user; the user ID the server runs as); If so you could use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html).

Comment: You could use the CopyManager API. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenCSV to read csv file into java object (here is an example - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mapping-csv-to-javabeans-using-opencsv/), and then use Java JPA Repository to insert data into database (here is an example - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-crud-repository-save)